# Load various set of retina graphics based on screen size

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, media-queries, retina-display

My setup is that I have a few versions of a site. On larger screens there is a slide show and on phones and other smaller screens there is just a scroll-through site. These two versions of the site load different graphics.

I've been puzzling over how to conditionally load retina graphics. I need to load the first set of retina graphics for retina devices that have screens big enough for the slide show, but if you're on a phone, the first set should not be loaded, and the second set of retina graphics should overwrite the second set of images used for the scroll-through site.

I'm using this to trigger and replace normal graphics with retina:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
```

That's at the beginning of my media queries and replaces the images for the desktop site. Then I have a few sections devoted to adjusting layout:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1099px){

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
// This query is for the small phone sized layout.

@media all and (max-width: 767px) and ((-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)) {
```

That last query is my attempt to swap retina images only for the phone site. This is not working and no arrangement I've tried has worked.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a jQuery plugin for this e.G. retina.js or response.js if you would like to offer different images based on screen resolution too.

This way you just have to upload the images in standard resolution and for retina displays with a @2x before the file extension. (retina.js, response.js is a lot more powerful but requires more work on your side)

Also I think you need to address the iphone 4 with a different media query.

-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1,5 should do the trick.